# Get decimal ascii value of a char

Tags: c++, char, type-conversion, ascii

I need to get a decimal ascii value of a char. Till now there was no problem to print it(avoiding negative values)using this.

```
char x;
cout << dec << (int)x << endl;
```

The problem comes when i want to assign the `dec` value to a `int` variable, `dec` cannot be used outside of the `cout`. Any suggestion how to do this? Note that `(int) char` wont work since I will get negative values as well and i want to avoid them.

I already tried with `atoi` and `unsigned int`, but so far, no luck.

Comment: why `<< dec` it's redundant

Comment: You cannot assume ASCII is being used - or any particular encoding. C and C++ are ostensibly encoding agnostic - your program could be run in an environment that uses EBCDIC, for example.

Comment: `cout << (int) x;` not `(int)char`

Comment: If `x<0`, it's not ASCII.

Comment: @Dai Why? I pretty much can and will assume ASCII is used. I know it is on 99.95% on machines out there. The rest may, with all due respect, find their software elsewhere. I have no obligation to produce 100% portable software 100% of the time.

Comment: Why `<< dec` ? i dont know why, but i have a `array` of `char` of size 1024. If i dont put `<<dec` i get negative values. Im using VB2015

Comment: @Capie What on earth does this question have to do with VB?

Comment: @Raindrop7 They lied to you.. [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

Comment: @Dai , just commenting in case it affects on something. I wrotte it just in case.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "decimal ASCII value"? ASCII codes are not decimal or hexadecimal or binary, they are *integers*.

Comment: @n.m. if u writte "ascii table" on google you will see lot´s of tables with 3 columns--> Decimal, hexadecimal and the symbol.

Comment: @Capie Decimal and hexadecimal are different *ways to write down* the *same* number.

Comment: @Raindrop7 That's what the standard (the S in ASCII) actually says: `The bits of the bit combinations of the 7-bit code are
identified by b7, b6, b5, b4, b3, b2, and b1, where
b7 is the highest order bit (most significant bit), and
b1 is the lowest order bit (least significant bit). The
bit combination may be interpreted to represent num-
bers in the range 0 to 127`.

Comment: @Raindrop7 ASCII is a **SEVEN** bit code. Just read the standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is enough to cast an object of type `char` to an object of type `unsigned char`. For example

```
char c = CHAR_MIN; 

int x = ( unsigned char )c;
```

or

```
int x = static_cast<unsigned char>( c );
```

Answer (score 1):

it depends on implementation of compiler,
some compilers implement char as unsigned,and allow extended ASCII characters (http://www.ascii-code.com/)
, below two links has the same code, and only one works
http://ideone.com/72Iiaz // uses gcc c++ 4.* and does not compile
http://ideone.com/hbmBK6 // uses c++ 14

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int main(){
    char ch = 'x';
    int num = ch;
    cout<<ch<<" => " << num << endl;
    ch = 'µ'; // should now have an extended ascii character
    num = ch;
    cout<<ch<<" => " << num << endl;
    cout<<" using unsigned "<< (unsigned int) 'µ';
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ use `static_cast<int>( someCharValue )` to convert a `signed char` (and `unsigned char`) value to an integer - but this is not a meaningful operation because `char` is an integer type anyway.

If you want a decimal string then use C++11's `std::to_string` function:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

char someChar = 'A';
int someCharAsInteger = static_cast<int>( someChar ); // this step is unnecessary, but it's to demonstrate that they're all just integers.
string someCharsNumericIntegerValueAsDecimalString1 = to_string( someChar ); // as there is no `to_string(char)` implicit upsizing to `int` will occur.
string someCharsNumericIntegerValueAsDecimalString2 = to_string( someCharAsInteger );

cout << someCharsNumericIntegerValueAsDecimalString1 << endl;
cout << someCharsNumericIntegerValueAsDecimalString2 << endl;
```

This will output this:

```
65
65
```

...assuming your system is ASCII.

Comment: Will check tomorrow and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

you can cast a character to an integer either through an explicit conversion or an implicit one:

```
int a = 'a'; // implicit conversion
cout << a << endl; // 97

int A = (int)'A'; explicit conversion
cout << a << endl; // 65
```